Share gcloud auth between docker services and host
i'm trying to run e2e tests using cypress, the idea is to pull the backend image from gcp, spin it up and run the tests against it, if all goes well, deploy the front-end image
the issue that i'm running into is that i need to authenticate to gcp before pulling the backend image, to do so, i'm using google/cloud-sdk:latest for authentication, wait for it ( using healthchecks ) then pull the backend image, chatgpt said that mounting - "~/.docker:/root/.docker" should share auth credentials between the host and gcloud service but i keep getting Unauthenticated request although i do see Activated service account credentials for: ... in the logs

how can i authenticate inside gcloud service and share the credentials with the host to pull the backend image ?

here's my docker-compose :
version: '3.8'

services:
  gcloud:
    image: google/cloud-sdk:latest
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "gcloud", "auth", "list"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 90s
      retries: 5
    volumes:
      - "/builds/shared_path:/mnt"
      - "~/.docker:/root/.docker"
    networks:
      - default
    command: bash -c "
        gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=/mnt/CREDS.json && 
        gcloud auth configure-docker gcr.io"

  backend:
    image: gcr.io/[gcpProject]/[backendImage]:1.0.1
    depends_on:
      gcloud:
        condition: service_healthy
    environment:
      - GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/mnt/CREDS.json
      - ENV=local
    volumes:
      - "/builds/shared_path:/mnt"
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
    command: bash -c "
      cp /mnt/.env .;
      uvicorn services.main:app --reload --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8001 --forwarded-allow-ips=\"*\""

  cypress:
    image: cypress/included:latest
    depends_on:
      - backend
    environment:
      - REACT_APP_BASE_URL=http://backend:8001
      - CYPRESS_E2E_URL=http://localhost:3000
    volumes:
      - ./:/e2e/
      - ./cypress-entrypoint.sh:/e2e/cypress-entrypoint.sh
    working_dir: /e2e
    entrypoint: [ "bash", "/e2e/cypress-entrypoint.sh" ]

networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge  # Default network

and relevant CI script :
cypress-test:
  image: docker:24.0.5
  services:
    - docker:dind
  stage: test
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  before_script:
    - mkdir -p /builds/shared_path
    - cp ${GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CREDS} /builds/shared_path/CREDS.json
    - printf "%s" "${BACKEND_ENV_FILE}" > /builds/shared_path/.env
  script:
    - export DOCKER_DEBUG=1
    - docker-compose up -d gcloud 
    - docker-compose up -d backend
    - docker-compose run --rm cypress
    - docker-compose logs -f cypress
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - cypress/videos/**/*.mp4
      - cypress/screenshots/**/*.png
    expire_in: 1 day
  allow_failure: false


is there a better approach ? i was hoping that adding google/cloud-sdk:latest as a service would save me the hassle and be able to remove gcloud from docker-comopse and do the auth in the before_script like so ( but it's not working, gcloud command not found )
like
cypress-test:
    image: docker:24.0.5
    services:
      - docker:dind
      - google/cloud-sdk:latest



a working alternative is using google/cloud-sdk:latest as the main image but that requires manual installation of docker-compose and using docker as the main image requires manual installation of gcloud, i want to avoid manually installing packages

Unfamiliar with GitLab but Google Artifact Management includes an example using the standalone credential helper and Workload Identity Federation which is a good solution.
